# django-debug-toolbar logging doesn't work?

Tags: django

I can't figure out how to use this plugin...

```
def homepage(request):
print request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
print 'test'
return render(request, 'base.html')
```

after this , in logging tab some output must appear. In console i've got:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13
>   test

in django-debug-toolbar logging tab i have "No messages logged."

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module for this to work.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('Test')
```

django-toolbar intercepts this call and will add it to the toolbar.  When you do `print('test')` it just goes to standard out.